# Which hook(s) are triggered when WooCommerce product stock is updated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom field in my products, that needs to be updated through a function, whenever the stock in any of the variations change.

Are there hooks for this? If so, which ones and what is their output (`$post_id` for example)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for *woocommerce_reduce_order_stock* action.
More info about this [hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#1376).

Here is a whole [list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) of available hooks.

-- EDIT

Function should look like this:

```
function test( $order ) { // you get an object $order as an argument
  $items = $order->get_items();
  $items_ids = array();
  foreach( $items as $item ) {
    $items_ids[] = $item['product_id'];
  }
  die( print_r($items_ids) ); // it should break script while reduce stock
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'test' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited my answer with some code, should it work like this? Should the function get fired?

Comment: It works! Or at least, the function does. The printing of the order items doesn't, so there's no way of knowing what's in them. Would you happen to know how to get their ID's?

Comment: Got it! Works with "$item['product_id']", thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

I have achieved the same using `woocommerce_product_set_stock` and `woocommerce_variation_set_stock` hook.

These hooks run when the stock **is changed** (either increased, or decreased). Even after the stock is decreased after product purchase.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'stock_changed' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'stock_changed' );
function stock_changed( $product ) {
    // Do something
}
```

---

Since WooCommerce 4.9+, `woocommerce_product_before_set_stock` and `woocommerce_variation_before_set_stock` are added to signal that the value of `stock_quantity` for a product/variation **is about to change**.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_before_set_stock', 'stock_about_to_change' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_before_set_stock', 'stock_about_to_change' );
function stock_about_to_change( $product ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the product object stock quantity is the same in both hooks. Any suggestion on why and how to get the stock value before the product stock is updated?