# Wordpress WooCommerce - Listen when a product is back in stock (From 0 stock quantity to 1) in PHP or script

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there a function that I can use to listen when a product stock quantity is changed from 0 to 1? I want to call a firebase endpoint when the product is back in stock (send a push notification). Should I write a PHP function or make my own plugin? Or should I make a script in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294861/woocommerce-run-function-when-stock-is-updated

Comment: Thanks! I looked into it. Going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 action hooks I use are 'woocommerce_product_set_stock' and 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock'

```
    add_action('woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'processStockChange', 1);
    add_action('woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'processStockChange', 1);
    /**
     * @param WC_Product $product
     */
    public function processStockChange(WC_Product $product)
    {
        if (
            $product->get_stock_quantity() > 1
        ) {
            ....Do something
        }
    }
```

you can place this in your theme `functions.php`

Comment: Hey Barrie, thanks for your detailed answer. Can I also get the product id or name? Can I do something like this: $product. id. Or wouldn't that work?

Comment: The object sent to the action is the WC_Product model as such you should be able to use all methods inside that class ie: ID
```
$product->get_id();
```

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you! I am going to try it out

Comment: Hey Barrie I came up with a question. Where do you call processStockChange? Do I need to call this function in the constructor? Because it needs to listen for a product quantity change

Comment: @jay You don't call it in the common sense, it's hooked to a action listener ie: `woocommerce_product_set_stock`, so when the hook is triggered the callback `processStockChange` is fired. A good help is the hooks: https://woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Aah okay, thanks man! Do you know what the 1 means at the end? add_action('woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'processStockChange', 1);. I saw in another post that he removed the number 1.

Comment: it's optional, 1 is so that it fires early if theres a stack of actions against that hook.
Have a read on this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Aahh okayy, so it's a priority thingy. Thanks!