# Check if product back to stock from 0 to 1 or more on product update in Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to check if product back to stock from 0 to 1 or more on product update in Woocommerce .
I check several methods but What I wanted did not happen.
I already check this link below but it has some bug for example when you set stock from 50 to 25 it will work but I want it to only work when stock update from 0 to 1 or more.

[Wordpress WooCommerce - Listen when a product is back in stock (From 0 stock quantity to 1) in PHP or script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737714/wordpress-woocommerce-listen-when-a-product-is-back-in-stock-from-0-stock-qua)

```
function kral_process_back_to_stock($product) {
    if ($product->get_stock_quantity() > 1) {
        update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_kral_sssss', 'hoyaa');
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'kral_process_back_to_stock', 1);
add_action('woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'kral_process_back_to_stock', 1);
```

I already check this method but this method do `update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_kral_sssss', 'hoyaa')` when product stock update from 20 to 10 and I don't want this . I just want this function to work only when product stock status update from out of stock to in stock .

Comment: Please add the code that you added in your `functions.php` so that we could tell what mistakes you have done in your code. Please also write expectations using comments in code so that it's easy to understand what you expect from specific code line and what you're getting.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I updated my question . I give more information at bottom

Comment: Problem is in your logic, `if ($product->get_stock_quantity() > 1)` this line means when stock in DB is bigger than 1 then run your code. so you're telling different logic in your question but applying different logic in yours. you need to fix your logic

Comment: @VijayHardaha I know that my logic have problem . The question is how to solve my problem and listen if product status change from out of stock to in stock so do something