# Trigger process when a product is moved from *out of stock* to *in stock* in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, inventory-management

I need to trigger a process when a product is moved from *out of stock* to *in stock*. I've played with a number of hooks:

- `woocommerce_reduce_order_stock`
- `woocommerce_product_set_stock`
- `woocommerce_variation_set_stock`
- `woocommerce_product_before_set_stock`
- `woocommerce_variation_before_set_stock`

But none of the following hooks gives access to the **previous stock** to allow triggering only when moving from no stock to positive stock (which is why this case is unique).

I need to catch this when a product is changed by admin, API, or another process (refunded orders, etc.)

Is there a reliable hook or method for achieving this trigger?

---

**Note:** next question is related to my question: [Which hook(s) are triggered when WooCommerce product stock is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39294861/11987538), but as described earlier in my question the hooks mentioned in the answers do not suffice.

Comment: Have you tested this hook. woocommerce_product_set_stock and  woocommerce_variation_set_stock

Comment: Try this one hook woocommerce_product_set_stock I think this one hook is helpful in this one scenario.